# How many Honey do I need for a UltraMarathon 80K and 4400meters D+?

Tags: running, nutrition, calories, long-distance-running, marathon

I plan to drink Honey as my source of glycogen for a Ultra Marathon of 80 Kilometers and 4400 meters D+, I'm planning to do it between 12 and 14 hours, so my question is ***How much milliliters of Honey would I need?***

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is extremely narrow and hard to imagine it could be relevance to anyone else. Also extremely difficult to answer accurately.

Comment: @EricKaufman - Why on earth would you vote to close and then answer the question?

Comment: @JohnP I answered it first, then reviewed the criteria for closing, and thought it was pretty narrow and constituted a close vote.

Comment: @EricKaufman - Fair enough. Just seemed odd. :)

Comment: Long distance nutrition seems pretty on topic. This is a concern for anyone doing long distance since a marathon is at or above the body's limit for energy storage per popular opinion. "Difficult to answer accurately" is exactly why this should be an open question.

Comment: Just because you CAN use anything for fuel doesn't mean you should. Honey has a very high simple sugar content, which could end up being very rough on your stomach. Try this out in a training run and see how it goes. But generally speaking, you should aim for 140-300 calories per hour, as your body cannot absorb more than that.

Answer (score 1):

So that's:

- ~50 miles.
- 3.8 mph (50/3.8 = 13.2) *or* 16 minutes/mile
- 792 minutes (13.2 * 60) = 4,391 calories (for a 170lb average person)
- [Honey *generally* has 21 calories per 5ml](http://tracker.dailyburn.com/nutrition/generic_honey_5ml_calories), so that's 3 calories per ml.
- 4,391 (total calories) / 3 (calories per ml) = **1,463 ml**.

Feel free to double check my math on all of that, and it's based entirely on the average of a 170lb person. Training, altitude, terrain, weight, temperature, and other factors affect this greatly.

Your body is also capable of storing, with [carboloading](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19122/5k-carbo-loading-benifits/19123), roughly 2,000 calories so theoretically you don't need to ingest 4,391 additional.

Comment: fine the calculations, but where is the fact that the body can just absorb calories from 240 to 280 per hour?

Comment: @Artemination - This is just basic calorie math, and pretty much irrelevant to your personal situation. Some people can't absorb honey without a lot of water, people's calorie absorption rates vary wildly. The best way to find out is to use honey in practice and see how you feel.

Comment: Heart rates provide another source for calorie loads and takes "effort" into account. I'd say you'd need about 6000-8000 calories for an ultramarathon, but it takes calories to burn calories and its hard to process this during a run. I'd like to hear some ultra marathoners and training specialists answer this...